# Next.js dependencies vs dev dependencies

Tags: next.js, dependencies, config

I opened a [PR](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/48076) for Next.js but it was closed because the thing it was fixing wasn't a problem and it was intended, I got confused about how to deal with dependencies and dev dependencies in Next.js, they said that Next.js has automatic dependency tracking via the option `output: standalone`, what is confusing is that this isn't set by default in the `next.config.js`, should I set it or not, should I install anything as a dev dependency?